# How to make cells have a gradient background?

Tags: swift, cell, gradient, viewcontroller

I have inserted a table view on my view controller and I was wondering how can I give the cells in the table view a gradient background? Can I edit each cell individually to give it a different color gradient background for each cell? For example, each cell is labeled after an index in the `trainingLevels` array, how could I make to where each has a different color gradient background?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var trainingLevels = ["Ball Handling", "Shooting", "Defense", "Advanced Drills", "Vertimax Drills", "Full Workouts", "BHB Products"]


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: TableView!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return trainingLevels.count
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "bell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = trainingLevels[indexPath.row]

    //cell details
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white



    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Subclass `UITableViewCell` and set the background via a gradient layer.

Comment: is it required to set gradient for each cell ? just set a gradient color for background and it will give same effect in each of your cell According to me it may lag if you provide gradient in each cell

Answer (score 9):

You can create extension of UIView:

```
extension UIView{
    func addGradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor){
        clipsToBounds = true
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        print(gradientLayer.frame)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

And inside your cell simply:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.addGradientBackground(firstColor: .green, secondColor: .blue)
}
```

Comment: Add this line only in Xib file otherwise when cell be reload then is add multiple Gradient in cell 
`self.addGradientBackground(firstColor: .green, secondColor: .blue)`

Comment: I have an identical extension for a gradient in a uiview but I found that, depending on the screen size, the gradient either wont fill the width of the cell when used in awakeFromNib(), or fills incorrectly when used in layoutSubviews(). draw(_ rect: CGRect) seems to update properly though.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create the gradient first and then insert sublayer to your cell like below.

```
func gradient(frame:CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.frame = frame
    layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.5)
    layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1,0.5)
    layer.colors = [ 
    UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    return layer
}

//Now on your tableViewcell do below

cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(cell.bounds), atIndex:0)
```

for Swift 4.0

```
func gradient(frame:CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame = frame
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        layer.colors = [
            UIColor.gray.cgColor,UIColor.cyan.cgColor]
        return layer
    }

    cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(frame: backgroundView.bounds), at:0)
```

Comment: I recommend that the `cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(cell.bounds), atIndex:0)` line is placed inside a subclass of UITableViewCell's awakeFromNib() function, and replace the `cell` with `self`. It could easily cause scrolling lag if that line is in the tableView(cellForRowAt:) function.

Comment: How would implement replacing `cell` with `self`?

Comment: also says `cgcolor` is unavailable in swift