# iOS Gradient color isse in collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, gradient, chameleon

I am facing this issue while setting gradient color to view inside the collection view

When its plotted at first time its fine.
but when I select some option and reload collection for the same it's happening like the second image.

viccalexander/Chameleon (https://github.com/viccalexander/Chameleon)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant code regarding the *specific* problem. The link to the entire project isn't bad, but put a block of code that's not working the way you expect into your question. Be more specific about the problem itself, too.

Comment: And also upload image what result exactly need?

Comment: I guess you are applying the gradient when the cell size hasn't been set yet. When it's been set, changes the bounds of the gradient layer to the one of the cell.

Answer (score 6):

Try below code, might help you

```
  extension UIView{
        func addGradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor){
            clipsToBounds = true
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
            gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            print(gradientLayer.frame)
            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        }
    }
```

And inside your cell simply:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.addGradientBackground(firstColor: .green, secondColor: .blue)
    }
}
```

Add this line only in Xib file otherwise when cell be reload then is add multiple Gradient in cell self.addGradientBackground(firstColor: .green, secondColor: .blue)

Reference - [How to make cells have a gradient background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518011/how-to-make-cells-have-a-gradient-background)

Comment: The same thing is happening with this code also brother, after selection new one, I reload the collection and this thing happens

Comment: @ShrikantWalekar can you please try this updated code.

Comment: Can you post the code, it would be more easier to understand the problem.!

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async *Worked* brother
i missed that... thank you